# how can I implement adaptive mergesort on hadoop clustering using mapreduce

Tags: sorting, hadoop, dictionary, merge, reduce

I want to implement adaptive merge sort on hadoop multinode clustering so that the run time reduces. But as far I did study map does sorting and grouping itself. I mean The map output is the input of reduce and the output of map we get is sorted (if I m not wrong). So how can I implement Adaptive merge sort? I mean is it possible?

Comment: you need to use secondary sorting to add your sorting logic on map output, you can follow [this link](http://www.bigdataspeak.com/2013/02/hadoop-how-to-do-secondary-sort-on_25.html)

Comment: thnx for ur response . I have written a adaptive merge sort in java.. can I run it in hadoop ? actually I m not understanding how to cnvrt the code into mapreduce whereas map does sorting.

Comment: just get my comments in answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In map reduce program if you want to apply your on sorting logic on map output so that reducer will get data in some sorted order you need to do following things

1. Choose your composite key
2. Set sort comparator class
3. Set grouping comparator class
4. Set partition class

For example if you have dataset like as below

UserID,ApplicationId,Datetime

And if you want to sort the row on basis of userid and Datetime

First you need to create a composite key class which consist of userid and datetime

Secondly you need to write sort comparator class in which you need to write your sorting logic

Thirdly you need to write grouping comparator class in which you want to compare value of keys on basis of one of the key not on basis of both the keys, like in this example we just want to group the record with userid only.

Fourthly you need to create partition class where you need to write logic to send the data of same userid to same reducer.

Last you need to set all classes under job instance

```
job.setSortComparatorClass(YourSortComparator.class);
job.setGroupingComparatorClass(YourGroupingComparator.class);
job.setPartitionerClass(YourPartitioner.class);
```